# Creating a dynamic input for a form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a requirement for multiple tasks to be populated dynamically in response to a user 'add task' button. I don't know how many tasks will be created by the user and would prefer not to set a maximum number with hidden fields as this would be inefficient with regards to database storage space.

Tasks can be thought of as child elements to notes and are stored in separate tables. I've managed to display multiple tasks on the view but I'm less confident with front-end development and am unsure of how I can add an input field without calling a post-back, thus entering 'mid-stream save' territory..

```
<html>
<div class="container">
  <!-- @using(Html.BeginForm()) { -->
  <div>
    <label asp-for="Note">Note</label>
    <input id="Note" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Note"></span>
    <label asp-for="Task">Task</label>
    <input id="Task" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Task"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button">Add Task</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
  </div>
  <!-- } -->
</div>

</html>
```

I have also made a small jQuery function that can create task inputs upon the 'add task' button, but with little success in connecting it to the controller/model.

I've had AJAX with JSON recommended to address this requirement but I'm unsure of how this can be implemented in a form and how this can then be read by the controller and ultimately the model?

I'm open to design alternatives, should it better suit my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'll try to explain here the approach I usually use to this type of problems, after quite a while developing different applications it finished as one of my favorites.

First of all, If I'm understanding you well, you have a view where a form is build, as a part of a client interaction you need to inject elements that depends on the main entity of your form (usually as a one to many relationship). I will call those "subforms" during this answer.

You need to:

A) Manage client interaction with the elements added/modified/replaced

B) Send the final data to your server's controller so data can be persisted into database.

My approach to this type of situations is try to manage all the client interactions in the client, sending final data only on the end, after user pushes "Save" button.

Obviously... this is not valid for EVERY situation, as sometimes specific requirements could make this solution not recommended.

For the client part:

I build the core of the form on a normal way, through a standard view, usually I place specific containers to inject there the information of the "dynamic" data.

On the "Add task" button I add a listener that creates the HTML for one element of the subform and appends it to the container. Usually this code includes a delete button to eliminate it from the DOM as a whole. I also have a listener to manage those interactions.

Ok... so you now have a form where some buttons can add and remove small parts of code that represents individual elements of your subform.

Include in your client code a data structure (I usually use a JSON object) that represents a list of elements of the subform.

When your user hits the "Save" button, capture the event and, before sending data back to server make this two things:

1. Loop through your subform structure reading the info that it contains at this moment and store it in your client data structure (the JSON object I refer before). Now you have a JSON object with all your subform information.
2. Stringify it and store it in a hidden text component which is sent within the form. All of your "subform" fields could be outside of the form, as they doesn't need to be sent, the info travels back to the server in a "class instance" as a JSON structure.

In the server:

When your controller receives your form data, there will be a field which stores a string representing the whole info your user sent through the "subform".

Now you just need to get this info and manage it in the way you like. You can, for example, design a class to load this type of info and send it to the database through your usual persistence engine.

Keep in mind that in this package you are storing not only the elements added, you also have the elements that have been changed since the last edit, so you will probably have to look for them in the database and modify them.

This is quite a wall of text, and probably it's less clear to understand the idea than it's on my mind, so feel free to ask if you don't understand something or there is anything that is not clear enough.